# Many to many relationship queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm a bit confused about many to many relationship tables, and the code that goes with them.

I have `table1`:

```
id, username
```

And `table2`:

```
id, votes_up, votes_down
```

And a helper table (`htable`):

```
vu, vd, adsid
```

What I want to happen is, when an ad is voted up or down, this vote doesn't go to all adverts.

My attempt at selecting data:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * 
             FROM dbo.tab2 
             INNER JOIN dbo.htable 
             WHERE tab2.votes_up = htable.vu 
                AND htable.votes_down = htable.vd 
             INNER JOIN dbo.tab1 
             WHERE htable.adsID = table1.ID");
```

And my insert attempt:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO dbo.htable (vu, vd, adsid)  
             VALUES 
             (SELECT FROM dbo.tab2.votes_up, dbo.tab2.votes_down , dbo.tab1.id)");
```

My question: Are these two queries correct? If not, how can I fix them? and what is the update query ?

Comment: I can barely understand what you're saying. Try to be more articulate. Also, you should provide more code examples, and maybe a more understandable table structure example. From what I can tell right now, you should just use several one-to-many relationships and it should be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not really understand your question, but your SQL queries are wrong. They should probably be something like:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    dbo.tab2 as tab2
    INNER JOIN dbo.htable as htable
        ON tab2.votes_up = htable.vu
        AND tab2.votes_down = htable.vd
    INNER JOIN dbo.tab1 as tab1
        ON htable.adsID = tab1.ID
```

and

```
INSERT INTO dbo.htable (vu, vd, adsID)
    SELECT
        votes_up, votes_down, ID
    FROM
        dbo.tab2
```

Comment: i have tried this code as you said but its seems just writing in my php file it does not seem as code , as i wrote

Comment: These are simply the SQL statements. You have to pass them to the PHP mysql_query() function to actually execute them. And you also have to write code to handle the result of your SELECT query, but you should do that yourself, since I have no idea what the rest of your code looks like.

Comment: i have done your code , but it didnt insert to htable , nothing , and when voting forexemple votes_up > 45 and i vote then it will be 46 , and when i refresh the page it will be 45 again and nothin happen in database . any error here ?

Comment: Without some more details of your actual code I'm afraid I cannot help you any further.

Comment: in my page i have the code of updating like that :   $sth = voting::db()->prepare('UPDATE '.voting::config('database_table_prefix').'tab2 SET name = ?, closed = ?, votes_up = ?, votes_down = ?, date = ? );
  //$sth->execute(array($this->name, $this->closed, $this->votes_up, $this->votes_down, $this->date, $this->id));                                                              how to write your code up like this code ?

Comment: It looks like your code is using PDO with prepared statements. For more details read about it in a tutorial, for example http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html#10. Also note that this site is a Q&A site, and not a "please write my code for me" site. You should do some work yourself based on the answers you receive.